# Are there security risks to enabling 32-bit applications to run on Windows 10?

Tags: malware, virus, protection, gaming

I'm installing an old game (32-bit) on my laptop (Windows 10 64-bit). This [guide](https://www.lemmingsforums.net/index.php?topic=5349.msg89194#msg89194) suggests enabling 32-bit applications to run with Internet Information Services (ISS), with the following steps:.

> 1. In Windows Search, type "features." Choose the Control Panel app "Turn Windows features on or off" under 'best match'.
> 2. Check the box beside "Internet Information Services" and click OK to install. It will take about 30 seconds. Close the dialog when done.
> 3. In the Windows Search, type "IIS." Choose the app "Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager" under 'best match'.
> 4. Once open, navigate to the left pane (under "Connections") and you will see your PC listed. Click the arrow to Expand and choose "Application Pools".
> 5. In the main part of the window, right-click on "DefaultAppPool" and choose Advanced Settings from the context menu.
> 6. Under 'General', click on "Enable 32-bit Applications", click the arrow and change the value from 'False' to 'True'.
> 7. Restart your PC.

I was just wondering whether using this particular method of running/installing 32-bit apps would cause any security issues or make my laptop more vulnerable to attacks/malware etc.?

Thanks.

Comment: IIS is a web server.  I very much question why it would be useful to do anything with IIS at all on a typical desktop machine.

Comment: This guide is pointless. Windows 10 can already run 32 bit applications without any extra features. It's built-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've actually got two questions there:

1. Are there security risks to running 32-bit applications on Windows 10?

None worth worrying about.  There are some minor risks such as the 32-bit address space limiting the amount of address randomization possible, but they'd only be an issue if you're under attack from a three-letter agency or the like.

2. Are there security risks to following the quoted instructions?

Very much so.  What those instructions have you do is install a web server, but they don't do anything to secure it.  They also don't have anything to do with running 32-bit applications -- Windows 10 supports 32-bit applications by default.